# Ansible aws s3 fails on directory checksuom when getting an object

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

when getting an object from an S3 bucket using the following Ansible command:

```
- name: "copy object from s3://{{ s3_bucket }}/{{ s3_object }} to {{ dest }}"
  s3:
    bucket: "{{ s3_bucket }}"
    object: "{{ s3_object }}"
    dest: "{{ dest }}"
    mode: get
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: [som_fake_host]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "aws_access_key": null,
            "aws_secret_key": null,
            "bucket": "some-fake-bucket",
            "dest": "/some-fake-dest/",
            "ec2_url": null,
            "encrypt": true,
            "expiry": "600",
            "headers": null,
            "ignore_nonexistent_bucket": false,
            "marker": null,
            "max_keys": "1000",
            "metadata": null,
            "mode": "get",
            "object": "some_fake_file",
            "overwrite": "always",
            "permission": [
                "private"
            ],
            "prefix": null,
            "profile": null,
            "region": null,
            "retries": 0,
            "rgw": false,
            "s3_url": null,
            "security_token": null,
            "src": null,
            "validate_certs": true,
            "version": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "attempted to take checksum of directory: /some-fake-dest/"
}
```

additional useful information:

- The destination directory exists
- The user that runs the playbook has permission on the destination directory
- The file exists in S3 bucket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/s3_module.html):

> `dest` The destination *file path* when downloading an object/key with a GET operation.

Try to call module with file path, not directory. E.g.:

```
dest: "{{ dest }}/{{ s3_object }}"
```

or something.

Comment: thanks this worked
dest: "{{ dest }}/{{ s3_object }}"